# Not able to create custom Visual webpart for sharepoint online site in visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-web-part

I am new to Sharepoint online. I have to create Visual Webpart for sharepoint online site but when I am creating new project in visual studio it is not allowing me to create. showing Cannot connect to targeted site.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, SharePoint does not support SharePoint solution(including visual web part).
You may try [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).